How to implement tail sampling in open telemetry gateway collector for grpc error codes?
I have below policy for http error codes in my gateway collector config.yaml
{
name: error_traces,
type: numeric_attribute,
numeric_attribute: {
key: http.status_code,
min_value: 400,
max_value: 599
}
}
I have not been able to find configuration policy for
I tried putting in different values, but not able to understand what should be the type of attribute and attribute name and could not find any grpc examples for open telemetry tail sampling.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
